# What is the best way to keep info on 'stock levels' for a product in a database?

Tags: mysql, key, normalization

My database is called 'shopping' and it contains the following tables:

```
products (product_id, product_name, price, category_id)
product_category (category_id, cagtegory_name)
customers (customer_id, username, pass, fname, lname, email)
orders (order_id, order_date, product_id, customer_id)
```

Now I want to consider keeping records of each products stock levels.

i.e 
    product_id = 1 
    product_name = MICROSOFT Limited Edition Gears 5 Xbox One X, Tekken 7      & Project Cars 2 Bundle
    price = 449.99
    category_id = 2
    stock _id = 1   ( references stock_id in product_stock table ) :-/ ?

I have considered THREE approaches to storing 'stock info' on products.

Approach a) Add a new Column in products table called 'stock_level' simple, and valid since stock level is entirely dependent on its primary key in this situation.

Approach b) Create a new table called 'product_stock' , with the columns 'stock_id, and stock_level'.

The confusion is arising in the logic here.

For some reason, having gone with approach b,  I had made the primary key of product_stock table (stock_id) ALSO a foreign key, referencing back to the products table as:

```
product_stock.stock_id = products.product_id
```

i.e

```
product_stock.stock_id 1 REFERENCES BACK TO products.product_id 1
product_stock.stock_id 2 REFERENCES BACK TO products.product_id 2
```

etc etc

THE THIRD approach I thought about was keep the stock_id key as a Primary Key only, and sever the link back to Products table.  Then in products,  create a column called stock_id with is a FK referencing stock_id in product_stock table.

Which of the three approaches seems the best ?  I for some reason,  regret deleting the columns and relations set up which was giving me behavior as discussed in approach b.

The reason I liked approach b was because,  if you hover over each stock_id key in product_stock,  you can see instantly what product it relates to in the products table ( phpmyadmin ).

thoughts on this folks ?

Refer to question and read.

no need, its all on phpmyadmin and not required in this case.

refer to question.

Comment: LOL @ product_stock table having a MYISAM engine...

Comment: I searched the page for "MYISAM", but it only appears in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you explained, each product has only and only one stock value. The simplest way to proceed is to to store that information directly in a products table: option a) in your question.

Using a separated table would be useful if, for example, you were in a situation where you have several stores and you need to keep track of the stock level of each product in each store. You would then create a separated table, with a column to store the id of the product, another to store the id of the store, and a third column to store the level of this particular product in this particular stock.